# Django + uWSGI hold a long time to response

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm running a Django web application using Nginx and uWSGI. Now I meet a problem that the finish_process view in django

I have added logging at the begin and the end of Django `finish_process` view.
I make a request at 17:20:18, and the view finished at 17:20:48. But uWSGI  does not return response at this time, and after 577 seconds, it throws IOError when it try to write response to client, because nginx close the connection (uwsgi_read_timeout is 300 seconds).

My question is why uWSGI holds the response so long after Django handled the view? I'm a bit at a loss.

Django log:

```
[INFO]246 views.py/finish_process 2016-03-06 17:20:18: [VIEW][START] finish_process: id=4
[INFO]282 views.py/finish_process 2016-03-06 17:20:48: [VIEW][END] finish_process: id=4
```

uWSGI log:

```
Sun Mar  6 17:29:55 2016 - uwsgi_response_writev_headers_and_body_do(): Broken pipe [core/writer.c line 296] during POST /api/finish_process/ (10.11.16.251)
IOError: write error
[pid: 3275|app: 0|req: 48689/48688] 10.11.16.251 () {34 vars in 553 bytes} [Sun Mar  6 17:20:18 2016] POST /api/finish_process/ => generated 0 bytes in 577024 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 3 headers in 0 bytes (0 switches on core 4)
```

Nginx error.log:

```
2016/03/06 17:25:18 [error] 3052#0: *44561 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.11.16.251, server: skyline, request: "POST /api/finish_process/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/var/run/skyline.sock:", host: "10.11.16.253"
```

uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /var/run/skyline.sock
chdir = /opt/skyline
processes = 1
threads = 10
master = true
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=skyline.prod_settings
module = skyline.wsgi:application
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

Nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name skyline;
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 300;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/skyline.sock;
    }
}
```

**Updated:**

Solved. I made a mistake.

Comment: have you checked the obvious things: file permissions (what are nginx and uwsgi running as, root?).  Disk full?

Comment: Can you show your django view? If you're sending second line to log just before return in view, that doesn't mean django finishes processing request. There may be something left to do, for example template rendering. Try to add your logs in middleware and put it on first position in middlewares list.

Comment: @warath-coder uwsgi running as root, and nginx running as www-data, there still free space in filesystem.

Comment: @GwynBleidD Yeah, now I added logging in django.core.handlers.BaseHandler. I will post logs if strange behavior is produced.

Comment: Obvious question: what was the mistake that solved this problem for you?